# Dropdown submenu for small screen devices

Tags: html, css

I would like to use media queries to display on small screens, among others, a submenu within the menu (directly below the parent main-menu entry, not below the last main-menu entry). Here is what I have until now (which includes code on regular-screen devices), I am only having trouble creating the appropriate CSS for this inlined submenu:

```js
function toggleState() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff6a00;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown menu */

.dropDownP {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropDown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.dropDownContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropDownContent a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropDown:hover .dropDownContent {
  display: block;
}

.dropDownP:hover,
.dropDown:hover .dropDownP,
.dropDown a:hover {
  background-color: #ff6a00;
  color: white;
}


/* Small screen settings */

@media screen and (max-width: 1076px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropDown {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1076px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topnav.responsive img {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleState()">&#9776;</a>
      <a href="?l3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="?l2">Link 2</a>
      <div class="dropDown">
        <div class="dropDownContent">
          <a href="?o1">Option 1</a>
          <a href="?o2">Option 2</a>
        </div>
        <a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>
      </div>
      <a href="?l1">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative;` and `top: 40px` to `.topnav.responsive a`.

(Or let bootstrap do all this for you).